# iTunes Connect: How to create Bundle ID as part of other team?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

A customer has added me as 'App Manager' to their companies iTunes Connect portal. How can I upload my app to their account?

It always tells me I have no eligible bundle IDs and then sends me to create one in the developer portal "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles". If I create one there, I create it for my private account, not the customers.

Please help, I would really like to release the app...

Comment: You will have to inform your customer to add you in developer portal as well or you need to inform them create one

Comment: get the company's developer portal (developer.apple.com) credentials and create a bundle ID for your app there, or you can get the company to create a bundle ID for you

Comment: How can I add people in the developer portal? Or can I not find the option because I have a 'private' account?

Comment: Solved it, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to call the company, tell them to go to https://developer.apple.com/, go to 'People' and invite me as an admin. Now I can go to the 'Certificates, Identifier & Profiles' page, click on my Name at the top and pick 'Change Team'. There I can switch to the company.

Hope this helps someone else at some point.